# CakePHP - Set viewPath in relation to a folder within a Plugin (CakeDC Users Plugin)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakedc

How do I set the controller property [$viewPath](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Controller.html) to be set as a path to a folder within a plugin? 

I'm extending the Users controller of CakeDC users plugin but I would like to reuse the same views without having to duplicate them from `Plugin/users/View` copying to `app/View`. I would like to set the viewPath to be `Plugin/users/View` but when I do that its appending with path to app.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var $viewPath = APP_DIR.'/Plugin/[Plugin_Name]/View/';
```

Comment: Doesnt work. It will output 'app/Views/path/to/plugin/views' and what I want is 'app/Plugin/plugin_name/View/path/to/plugin/views'

Comment: Still does not work. It outputs 'app/View/app/Plugin/[Plugin_Name]/View/'. I think it appends whatever is in $viewPath to 'app/View' e doesnt allow to change to 'app/Plugin/View'.